# PIVOT to summarize data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL temp table (#tmpProdData) with data in the following format:

```
TransAmount | CommAmount | Role1 | Role2 | ... | Role20
100.00      | 15.00      | 123   | 123   | ... | 456
200.00      | 60.00      | 123   | 456   | ... | 456
250.00      | 25.00      | 456   | 789   | ... | 789
```

The Role1 through Role20 columns have an employee ID (int). I need a results table (#tmpEmpTotals) that looks like this:

```
EmpID | Role1TransTotal | Role1CommTotal | Role2TransTotal | Role2CommTotal | ... | ... | Role20TransTotal | Role20CommTotal
123   | 300.00          | 75.00          | 100.00          | 15.00          | ... | ... | 0.00             | 0.00
456   | 250.00          | 25.00          | 200.00          | 60.00          | ... | ... | 300.00           | 75.00
789   | 0.00            | 0.00           | 250.00          | 25.00          | ... | ... | 250.00           | 25.00
```

There should be 1 entry per employee that is in any role and then have the SUM(TransAmount) and SUM(CommAmount) if they were in that role. So if employee 123 was in Role1 in the #tmpProdData table, it would be added to his total for Role1TransTotal and Role1CommTotal. An employee could be in more than 1 role for the same record.

In the sample you can see that employee 123 is in role1 for the first and second records so his Role1CommTotal is the sum of the CommAmount for record 1 and 2.

I feel like PIVOT would be helpful here, but I can't seem to get it to work out properly. I CAN do it currently using a sub-select SUM but I know that's hugely inefficient. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, explain why you are using an unsupported version of SQL Server.

Comment: Updated question with sample data. SQL2008R2 is the database it is currently on and out of my control at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Do you want to unpivot and reaggregate?

```
select v.empid,
       sum(case when v.rnum = 1 then t.commamount end) as role1commission,
       sum(case when v.rnum = 2 then t.commamount end) as role2commission,
       . .  
from #tmpProdData t cross apply
     (values (1, role1), (2, role2), . . . 
     ) v(rnum, empid)
where v.empid is not null
group by v.empid;
```